# R loop for calculating matrix elements taking too long to execute

Tags: r, optimization

The following loop is taking a lot of time to run. If I comment the line inside, it runs quickly. `prices` is `3224x40` matrix.

```
get_returns <- function(prices, type=1) {  
  returns = prices
  returns2 = prices
  returns[,] = 0
  M = dim(prices)[1]
  N = dim(prices)[2]

  for (i in 2:M) {
    for (j in 1:N) {      
      returns[i,j] = prices[i,j]/prices[i-1,j] - 1   ## LINE 1
      returns2[i,j] = prices[i,j]/prices[1,j] - 1   ## LINE 1
    }
  }
}

> dim(prices)
[1] 3224   40

>
> system.time(get_returns(prices,1))
   user  system elapsed 
1213.95    1.12 1266.60 
> 

> # After commenting LINE 1
> system.time(get_returns(prices,1))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.67    0.00    0.75 
>
```

It is almost taking 20 minutes to run. I am wondering why would it take this long to run and if I can do something to optimize it. I have other loops which run fairly fast but this particular loop is a problem.

Comment: @user236215 : your runtime is simply crazy. Sure prices is a matrix?

Comment: yes its a matrix. You can probably set up a similar matrix with random values and notice this.

Comment: @user236215 : on my computer, this runs in 1.2 seconds... (`system.time(test <- get_returns(prices = matrix(runif(3224*40), ncol = 40)))
`)

Comment: I got the same result (1.22 seconds).

Comment: I got 0.58. I also find that get_returns needs return(returns) to return any value.

Comment: There are several functions to do this in packages you're probably already using (quantmod::Delt, quantmod::periodReturn, TTR::ROC, etc, etc).  Why re-re-reinvent the wheel?

Comment: because I have some other specific return calculations also. I don't know why this particular matrix loop is taking so long for me. But vectorization works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loops take too long in R. You need to take advantage of vectorization. For example, instead of your loop, try this:

```
returns <- prices[2:M,]/prices[1:(M-1),] -1;
```

See also the information in the [R inferno](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/S/Spoetry/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: wow. this ran almost instantly. This document is really enlightening. Thanks!

Comment: How would you change returns2 (edited original post) using vectorization? When I do `returns2 <- prices[2:M,]/prices[1,] -1`, I get error "Error in Ops.data.frame(prices[2:M, ], prices[1, ]) : / only defined for equally-sized data frames"

Comment: You could try `w=dim(prices)[2]; returns2 <- prices[2:M,]/matrix(prices[1,]-1, M-1, w);` Basically you make a matrix out of `prices[1,]` that is the same size as `prices[2:M,]`. But this requires a bit of memory.

Answer (score 0):

If prices is data.frame

```
sapply(prices,diff)/prices[-nrow(prices_df),]
```

If prices is matrix

```
apply(prices,2,diff)/prices[-NROW(prices),]
```